# Rails CanCanCan/RoleModel/Canard: limit to user doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, cancancan

Setup:

- Rails 5.1, Ruby 2.4.0
- User.rb created from Devise Extended with
  CanCanCan and Canard (which includes RoleModel)
- Collection has_many Items (Doed NOT work)
- Wishlist has_many WishlistItems (which DOES work)

From user.rb:

```
acts_as_user :roles => [ :guest, :user, :entity_admin, :admin, :super_admin ]
```

Those are stored in a roles_mask field in the user table (values map to 1, 2, 4, 8, 16).

On the Admin and Super_admin levels, things work fine, but it's defined as wide open, so that's expected:

```
manage[:all]
```

On the user level, it's restricted to items that the user owns:

```
# app/abilities/users.rb
Canard::Abilities.for(:user) do
  can [:read], :all

  can [:manage], Collection do |collection|
    collection.try(:user) == @user
  end

  can [:manage], Item, :collection => { user_id: user.id }

  can [:manage], Wishlist do |wishlist|
    wishlist.try(:user) == @user
  end

  can [:manage], WishlistItem do |wi|
    wi.try(:user) == @user
  end
end
```

I've also tried the simpler declaration:

```
can [:manage], Collection, user_id: @user.id
```

to no avail.

In the controllers, things are loaded and authorized accordingly:

```
# app/controllers/collections_controller.rb:6
load_and_authorize_resource :collection, except: [:index, :show, :create]

# app/controllers/items_controller.rb:6-7
load_and_authorize_resource :collection
load_and_authorize_resource :item, through: :collection

#app/controllers/collections_controller Finder method from before_action
private
def set_collection
  @collection = @user.collections.friendly.find(params[:id]).decorate
end
```

So I can create a collection, and in console it belongs to the correct user. **However, I get a CanCan error when I try to do any edits to it ("You are not authorized to access this page.").** Adding an item fails silently.

I'm sure this is user error on my part, but I can't figure it out for the life of me.

Comment: so... what's your error/issue?

Comment: bolded the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that the object being authorized with CanCanCan has been decorated. You can overload `can?` and `authorize!` in ability.rb with the following:

```
def can?(action, subject, *extra_args)
  subject_arg = subject.is_a?(Draper::Decorator) ? subject.model : subject
  super(action, subject_arg, *extra_args)
end

def authorize!(action, subject, *extra_args)
  subject_arg = subject.is_a?(Draper::Decorator) ? subject.model : subject
  super(action, subject_arg, *extra_args)
end
```

This will handle any occurrences of passing a decorated object into an ability check.